# How do I convert from .mp4 to .part?

Tags: video, file-format

I have a partially downloaded video file (the download was paused). It is a large file and a significant portion has already been downloaded. I accidentally renamed it to .mp4 and its format got changed to .mp4. But I need to convert it back to .part to resume the download. I tried renaming it to .part but that didn't change its format, just the name got changed.

How do I convert the file to .part format?

Comment: Renaming the file does not change the data or it's format in any way at all. No conversion has happened nor does it need to happen. http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=587642&sid=f2547cd122f2ac1547b8a59012a0d299

Comment: Also https://superuser.com/questions/1103143/how-to-resume-interrupted-firefox-download

Comment: What are you using to download it?  That matters for answers to get it to resume.

Comment: @headkase I am downloading it in firefox. I know a method to resume the download. But I need the .part file for the method to work. I had the .part file but I accidentally changed its format to .mp4. I need to convert it back to .part.

Comment: You don’t convert at all. You rename it back. The end.